# Class weights in RSNSS package?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, r, weighted-data

New to ML in general and have been Googling on this. I am working on a dataset that will rate each customer features to a credit worthiness class attribute.

Is it possible to add class weights in the 'mlp()' function to deal with imbalance of class attributes? I have read the official [document](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/RSNNS.pdf) for RSNNS package. There is a parameter that is `initFunc = "Randomized_Weight"` but the documentation does not offer any other `initFunc` options.

Can this be done on the `mlp()` parameters, or I have to do a class weightage before the `mlp()` step?